# near-simoultaneous create and delete database record query, which is faster or has higher priority?

Tags: sql-server, thread-priority

Lets say i have a multi-threaded web service to look for an old Identity record in order to create a new one based on it, and to remove the old one if it existed in the first place by using 2 Public methods:
- CreateIdentity 
- DeleteIdentity

even tough this scenario should be avoided since we all can think of the problems that will come from this, i was wondering what would happen if i send the create and then the delete right after it?

things i would like to know specifically:
- Has 1 of the 2 a higher priority so that for example all creates must precede deletes on a table?
- Is a delete action always faster than a create when we rule out prioritizing?

Comment: No amount of expertise with sql-server alone would be sufficient to answer this question.   Tag the language your web service is written in.

Comment: RE "for example all creates must precede deletes on a table": No they are the same priority, "Is a delete action always faster than a create when we rule out prioritizing?" When talking about table rows, No, Delete is slower, since delete first has to find the record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell how familiar you are with multi-threading so I'm not sure at what level to target this answer. The simple answer to your questions are;

- which is faster - could be either
- which has higher priority - neither

SQL Server manages concurrency, so you don't need to worry about being *able* to try and do both actions at the same time. If two actions on the same object were to happen at the same time the lock manager would handle any conflicts.

As to why either could be faster, I'm sure that one operation could be theoretically faster than the other, but in practice faster probably means 'finishes first', in which case real world delays like waiting, blocking and scheduling will make the difference.

SQL Server doesn't have the facility to prioritise commands, even if it did the point above still applies.

If you need the create to happen before the delete then you must manage this yourself. A single call to a stored procedure would be ideal, but if you have to use 2 calls then you must wait for the first to return before making the second. If you need both actions to be atomic then you will have to use a transaction.

Comment: This was the type of answer i was looking for even tough my question wasn't stated correctly apparently, since the focus of the replies was on the web service instead of how SQL handles these things. Thanks for getting my actual point @Rhys Jones

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server will execute the commands in the order it receives them.  You should wrap these in a transaction.  What if the create is successful but the delete fails, or vice-versa?  You can create a stored procedure to ensure that the actions happen in a certain order and having a transaction will ensure that if one operation fails, say to a connection loss, that the other operation will be rolled back.

Comment: "SQL Server will execute the commands in the order it receives them." - not true at all.

Comment: Of course it is true.  With no other considerations query execution begins when the command arrives, it will not wait to see what other queries are coming before deciding to execute.  I did not say that sql server will not start another query before the first one finishes.  If I am mistaken please provide documentation to the contrary as I would be very interested in expanding my knowledge.

Comment: @Joe C Thanks for your answer! But please read the full question before answering since i already stated the way of the scenario as something to avoid.. Now you come over as nitty-witty witch is not my intention! :)

Comment: At a theoretical technical level you might be right, but in the real world there's no way to guarantee the order of processing of two independent commands.